# Visibility of aliases in C# namespace

Tags: c#, using

I am a little confused about the visibility of aliases with the `using` directive.

I have a simple class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestUsing
{
    using StringList = List<string>;

    internal class Class2
    {
        public void processList(StringList sl)
        { }
    }
}
```

and I am consuming it in another file:

```
using TestUsing;

Class2 o = new Class2();
o.processList(new StringList());
```

But this doesn't compile as `StringList` is not recognized.

How do I make the alias in the `TestUsing` namespace visible to consumer of `Class2`?

Comment: It works fine when I do it, but I have to fully qualify it: `using StringList = System.Collections.Generic.List<string>;`.

Comment: I think it's less maintainable to use `StringList` rather than `List<string>`. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @Enigmativity This was just a simplified example, my actual alias is `List< <List<string> >` which is a lot of typing, if used frequently.

Comment: How about using a `global using` instead? If you just want to save some keystrokes, that is.

Comment: What are you using `List<List<string>>` to represent?

Comment: @Enigmativity Er, a list which contains lists of strings?

Comment: @Enigmativity "It works fine when I do it, but I have to fully qualify it". This doesn't work for me. Is there some compiler flag I am missing? I created these using the `Console Application` wizard on VS 17.5.3.

Comment: @DS_London - What are you using a list which contains lists of strings to represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up until C# 10, `using` and `using alias` directives were only local to your C# file and its scope (namespace). If you're using C# 10, you can use the global keyword and have your alias everywhere.

But if you're not, then no, aliases are not the option.

What you could do is create your own class that inherit from List

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestUsing
{
    public class StringList : List<string> { }
}
```

This can then be used everywhere you use TestUsing

Comment: I did think of this, but was reticent as my background is more C++ where it is bad practice to inherit from standard containers.

Comment: @DS_London - don't try to apply C++ thinking to C#. Although there are some similarities in syntax, they are different languages and you can be easily led astray by assuming too much similarity.

Comment: @DS_London Indeed, completely agree. In C++ you could simply use typedef for that, and if you ask me, this is really something that is missing in C#. But until that is a thing, we'll have to do.